# Неверный масштаб графики

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Есть `PNG` рисунок: черный контур на прозрачном фоне. Заливаю его на `PictureBox` так:

```
Graphics gr = pbx_StylePic.CreateGraphics();
Image im = Image.FromFile($"styles/shirt/{fileName}.png");
gr.DrawImage(im, new Point(0, 0));
```

Он становиться ровно как должен. Однако если я раскрою файл в фотошопе и НЕ МЕНЯЯ размера просто дорисую немного этот контур и пере-сохраню то вся картинка увеличивается и как следствие контур съезжает со своего места. Почему так? Кто сталкивался с тем же, подскажите решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Если просто пересохранить, размер в кб увеличился раз в 8 - 10 а разрешение осталось прежним. Масштаб уходит

Comment: В PNG случайно не хранится DPI ? Может быть в нем дело.

Comment: Все таки нет. меняя DPI меняется и размер в пикселях. А у меня остается неизменным 400х538

Comment: "меняя DPI меняется и размер в пикселях" откуда у вас такая информация?

Comment: alt+ctrl+I  в фотошопе, изменил dpi  -сохранил  - размер изменился.

Comment: DPI это просто флаг. Он не контролирует число пикселей. Просто снимите галку "Resample image".